# How to make sure goroutine fully runs before exiting

Tags: mongodb, go, goroutine, mgo

I have a function calling a go routine that calls additional functions within it.  However, those go routines are exiting before being completely finished.  How would I make sure all the underlying code within the function (migrateUserHelper) runs before the exit.  Here is my code below:

```
func MigrateUsers(){
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  userCount:=10 //userDAO.GetUserCount()
  limitSize:=2
  count:=0
  divisor = userCount/limitSize
  for divisor>0{
      wg.Add(1)
      go migrateUserHelper(limitSize,&wg,count)
      divisor =divisor -1
      count=count +1
  }
  wg.Wait()
  fm.Println("DONE BATCHES")
 }
 func migrateUserHelper(limitSize int, count int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) 
 {
   defer wg.Done()
   fmt.Println("Start batch "+strconv.Itoa(count))
   users:= userDAO.GetUsers(limitSize)
   fmt.Println("Fetched Users for batch "+ strconv.Itoa(count))
   userDAO.BulkUpdateUsers(users)
  fmt.Println("Reconciled Users for batch "+ strconv.Itoa(count))
}
```

Im trying to update  A LOT OF records in the database simultaneously in different go routines.

Thanks

Comment: Unless there is a panic or `main` returns before `MigrateUsers` finishes, all of the code will run. If that appears to not be the case when you run it, please provide more details - i.e. what makes you think it is not  running (log output etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) is a counting semaphore and can be used to count off goroutines as they finish their work, but for that, you need to set how many goroutines you are going to spawn. You can do that by calling the method [Add](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Add):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    migrateUsers()
}

func migrateUsers() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    userCount := 10
    limitSize := 2
    count := 0
    divisor := userCount / limitSize
    wg.Add(divisor)

    for divisor > 0 {
        go migrateUserHelper(limitSize, count, &wg)
        divisor = divisor - 1
        count = count + 1
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("DONE BATCHES")
}

func migrateUserHelper(limitSize int, count int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Start batch " + strconv.Itoa(count))
    fmt.Println("Fetched Users for batch " + strconv.Itoa(count))
    fmt.Println("Reconciled Users for batch " + strconv.Itoa(count))
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.com/p/dn6SjGoCwoX).

Comment: Hey, I was already using Add, just forgot to add it to the example.  Sorry, thanks.

Comment: It didnt solve the issue as I was already doing that, just forgot to copy that piece of code over

Comment: @pavbagel could you please provide a working example then? Your code [won't compile](https://play.golang.com/p/IvSXkCuG5Yq).